# How to implement google maps with PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I use PHP/MySQL/XHTML to create new entries:

I have those fields in the HTML form:

1. title
2. city
3. tags
4. price

How can I add a map for each entry? (to display the city position from google maps)

I need to store the position into mysql or just using javascript?

Comment: Do you mean you wish to add a google map to a web page you are constructing?  If so it is more of a Javascript question, as that is how you would achieve that goal usually.

Comment: Yes I want to add google map for each entry! I have a field called city, how can I show the correct city in each page

Comment: You didnt answered completely, do you wish to add map to webpage, or do u wish to save map showing the city in your database. As I see you said you have form with map as input, and you need the map to be saved, is it correct?

Comment: I want to display a small map for each entry (the key is the city field). an example here: http://demo.woothemes.com/estate/property/desert-wing-house/

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement such feature you won't take advantage of server side tech. Go through [Google Map API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html) to familiarize yourself with the basics. It's really a javascript issue.

Comment: Thanks! So I don't need to store any data into map field (mysql database)? I have a city field (New York / Chicago ...)

Comment: @Pascal Ideally you would store latitude and longitude, as that is the most accurate way to position the map.  There is a lookup routine that you could pass the city to (with country and anything else needed to get back a single result).  But you would be best storing the position.

Comment: Thanks How can I get the position for each city? no idea :-(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will use Google maps javascript api v3 use geocoding to find the lat,lng of the city and then if necessary store the coordinates in db for future use.